# Template int parameter from constant expression in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr

I have a template class:

```
template <int N>
class Object<N>
{
// ...
}
```

For example, I want to make a function which adds something inside and returns class with `int N` parameter set to max of them:

```
template <int N1, int N2>
Object<std::max(N1, N2)> AddObjects(const Object<N1> & object_1, const Object<N2> & object_2)
{
    // ...
}
```

And I must do it in C++11, but unfortunately not C++14 (where `std::max` is `constexpr`). Is it possible in C++11?

Comment: You may still write your own `constexpr` function `max`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Please, how to write it if in c++11 one cannot use if-else in constexpr functions?

Comment: In c++11, ternary operator seems required (I think there is some hack for branchless version for `int`/`uint`), In c++14, `constexpr` rules allow if else :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the ternary operator instead:

```
 template <int N1, int N2>
 Object<(N1 > N2)? N1 : N2> AddObjects(const Object<N1> & object_1, const Object<N2> & object_2) {
        // ...
 }
```

Comment: Wow! Never thought something like this is possible